# How to receive a arg from command line in C

Tags: c

I want to write a program to receive a argument from command line. It's like a kind of atof().

There my program goes:

```
  9     char s[] = "3.1415e-4";
 10     if (argc == 1) {
 11         printf("%e\n",atof(s));
 12     }
 13     else if (argc == 2) {
 14         //strcpy(s, argv[1]);
 15         printf("%e\n",atof(argv[1]));
 16     }
```

1.should I just use argv[1] for the string to pass to my atof(), or, put it into s[]?

2.If I'd better put it in s[], is there some build-in function to do this "put" work? maybe some function like strcpy()??

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would do it this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char defaultStr[]="3.1415e-4";
  const char *arg = NULL;
  if(argc <= 1)
  {
     arg = defaultStr;
  }
  else
  {
     arg = argv[1];
  }

  printf("%e\n", atof(arg));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for put it into `s`. Just use `argv[1]`.

Having said this, is you **are putting it into s anyway** (which is not that bad) make sure you change your code to:

```
char s[20];
strcpy(s, argv[1]);
```

Using `strcpy` with a constant char array is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass it as `argv[1]`, no need to copy it. Should you want to copy it, you need to ensure that `s` can actually hold the full string contained in `argv[1]`, and allocate a bigger array if not... so it is messier.

Comment: thank you, Pablo Santa Cruz and Péter Török.
But one thing confused me was that the argument's type is char *,how to put the argument into s[]?

Comment: @dennis, `char[]` __degrades_ into `char*` whenever needed. This means in practice that the underlying memory representation of the two are practically the same, and you can use the two notations interchangeably most of the time. The exception is, you can't reassign an array, i.e. `s = argv[1]` results in a compilation error. If you want to copy the _content_ of `argv[1]`, use `strcpy` as you mentioned.